# Dockerfile and background running mysql server

Tags: mysql, docker, background, dockerfile

i have problems...

Firstly i have a Dockerfile where i define all the steps, like updating system, installing mysql, change mysql root password.

Then i set an EntryPoint so my container on start will exec mysql server.

I have 2 problems:
- When i start the container, it restarts every 10 seconds.
- When i use exec to enter the docker it says: "No docker with such id".

This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
# Set the base image
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER redigaffi

RUN apt-get update \
&&  apt-get -y install mysql-server \
&&  service mysql start \
&&  mysqladmin -u root password FEGj5nmKYRha

ENTRYPOINT service mysql start \
        && bash

#VOLUME /root/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw Please run -v running this docker since Dockerfile has not access to host files

EXPOSE 3306
```

I put bash on the end on the entrypoint because without it container just closes, so it remains in background.

I have tried many commands to execute this container:

- docker run -d df0bb600c10f /bin/bash # This one closes the container after 2 seconds
- docker run -d --restart=always df0bb600c10f /bin/bash # This one remains, but restarts every 10 seconds and i cant access this docker using exec.

Please help, what is wrong ?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the official mysql or mariadb image?

Comment: Because i prefer an custom image, and for learning too.

Comment: Well, the main issue is that docker requires an active process but your entrypoint ends with `bash` which will not remain active, so it quits immediately. You need something like `tail -f file.log`, or `mysqld` like what they use in the official mysql image https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/a6f4c23621421bb708ad44616532d3d1cf44f6bf/5.7/Dockerfile

Comment: The thing is if i append tail -f at the end i can't access with an exec this docker through bash.

Comment: Interesting, also if i change the entrypoint, and exec the exec command will change too ? Also if my entrypoint is test.sh and i do a exec then test.sh will executed?

Comment: Sorry it was wrong. Should be `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`. I deleted the wrong comment.

Comment: Hey thanks man, i've got it !! PD:        Okay, i understand that without process docker will close, but i start my mysql with service mysql start, this create the mysql service process, why docker closes? it is a process :S

Comment: Hey, i have a problem, starting my docker if i add the flag -v /root/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw the  docker crashes after a while, what is wrong ?

Comment: Docker needs a front-end process, not a service or daemon process. For your error you need to look into the log file inside the container. It's hard to say what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the supervisor. This article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221070721/https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) shows the steps.